# Why this configuration is not possible for the Tower of Hanoi?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science

I am studying the Tower of Hanoi, and as I read through some posts on here about the proof of optimality for the optimal solution, I found a comment that said there cannot be deadlocks in the TH game. I took it to mean that the game is always solvable and set out to try proving this statement. However, I ended up with a legal-looking configuration that seems unsolvable.

Consider a game with $3$  pegs and $7$ disks, whose sizes are represented by $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7$.

$$\begin{array}[b]{c}
2 \\
3 \\
\text{Peg 1} \\
\end{array}
\quad
\begin{array}[b]{c}
1 \\
7 \\
\text{Peg 2} \\
\end{array}
\quad
\begin{array}[b]{c}
4 \\
5 \\
6 \\
\text{Peg 3} \\
\end{array}
$$

I believe this configuration is not possible. However, I can't seem to find a way to prove it. Please advise!

---

I'm not sure if I should start a separate thread for this, but I'd greatly appreciate it if someone could provide some insights into how one may approach proving the solvability of TH game, just in case I couldn't prove it myself. If you do, please indicate this part from the rest of your answer so I could recognize it and stop reading further. Thank you!

Comment: It’s possible to move the $1$ to Peg 1. Then it’s possible to move the $1,2,3$ to Peg 3. Then it’s possible to move the $1,2,3,4,5,6$ to Peg 2.

Comment: @peterwhy yes thank you very much! I see it now. It's so dumb of me T.T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disks $1$ through $6$ can be sorted and stacked onto peg $3$ with the following sequence of moves:

$$1 \to 3 \\
2 \to 2 \\
1 \to 2 \\
3 \to 3 \\
1 \to 1 \\
2 \to 3 \\
1 \to 3,
$$
where the notation $a \to b$ means moving disk $a$ to peg $b$.  Since it is possible to sort the first $6$ disks onto a single peg, it is possible to move disk $7$ to a different peg--in this case, peg $1$ if it was not already on $1$.  If disk $7$ was already on peg $1$, then the standard sequence of moves of the stack $1$-$6$ on peg $3$ will move it onto disk $7$, solving the puzzle.

Comment: Thank you so much! I see it now!